# IPython notebook to slides: Reveal is not defined

Tags: javascript, jupyter-notebook, reveal.js

I'm using nbconvert to make a reveal.js slideshow from my notebook. Specifically, I'm running: `ipython nbconvert --to slides analysis.ipynb`. This creates "analysis.slides.html", and I put "reveal.js" in the same folder. That is, I have:

- reveal.js

  - ...
- analysis.ipynb
- analysis.slides.html

However, when opening "analysis.slides.html" in the browser JavaScript console, I get the following:

```
analysis.slides.html:1992 Uncaught ReferenceError: Reveal is not defined
analysis.slides.html:2032 Uncaught ReferenceError: Reveal is not defined
require.min.js:8 Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function () {
        root.Reveal = factory();
        return root.Reveal;
    }
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#mismatch
```

I don't get a 404 error for the line which loads reveal.js - `<script src="reveal.js/js/reveal.js"></script>` - so any ideas why I might be seeing the errors I am?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Saw in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28231114/4244561) that reveal.js version 3.0.0 isn't compatible with IPython, so the solution is to use an older version, e.g. `ipython nbconvert --to slides analysis.ipynb --reveal-prefix "http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/reveal.js/2.6.2"`.

Comment: Note that you may have to use `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/reveal.js/2.6.2` (note the http*s*). At least in my case, I couldn't get any of the jsdelivr content without it.

Answer (score 2):

@harshil's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30128179/623735) is right on. But if you want a clean way to stay up-to-date with reveal.js and evolve with jupyter (ipython notebook), building on @Lev's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28231114/623735) is a bit better:

```
git submodule add https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js.git
cd reveal.js
git checkout 2.6.0
```

And when ipython upgrades, you can just checkout that new version (tag) in your reveal.js git submodule.