# How to convert jupyter notebook to slides

Tags: jupyter, reveal.js

I have jupyter notebookrunning correctly. I have cloned reveal.js from github. I want to convert a jupyter notebook to an html slideshow but have have only found instructions on how to do this from the command line. However, jupyter is not a recognized command from the cmd window. I have tried navigating to the below folder, and adding it to my environment path but still have not been successful:

```
D:\Python37\Scripts
```

It is on a work machine, so I don't have control over where and how python/jupyter are installed. I think they used anaconda to install python and the other packages.

Can you do this via a jupyter notebook directly instead of the command line?

Answer (score 0):

While running the given notebook turn on the *cell toolbar* in the `View` menu, then specify the slide type for each cell. (As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20441848/how-do-i-separate-slides-when-exporting-an-ipython-notebook-to-reveal-js#answer-33714574).)
Afterwards select `File/Download as/Reveal.js slides`.
And there you go.
(At least this is working using the Beakerx version of jupyter.)